# Riemann Sums Approximation

Tags: real-analysis, integration, solution-verification, riemann-integration, partitions-for-integration

Let P = {$-10,-2,0,1,5$} and $f:=[-10,5]-> \mathbb{R}$ given by:

$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
 4&\text{if}\, x= 0\\
 \frac{x+2|x|}{|x|}&\text{if}\, x\not=0
\end{cases}
$

I need to find a partition Q of $[-10,5]$ such that $U(f,Q)-L(f,Q)<0.001$.

My method: I worked out that $Q_n$ = {$-10+\frac{15i}{n}, i =0,1,2,....,n-1,n $}, so $x_i = -10 + \frac{15i}{n}$ and $x_i - x_{i-1} = \frac{15}{n}$. Hence, $m_i = -10 + \frac{15i-15}{n}$ and $M_i = -10 + \frac{15i}{n}$.

Now, $L(f,Q_n)$ = $\sum \limits_{i-1}^{n}({-10} + \frac{15i-15}{n})(\frac{15}{n})$ = $\frac{-75n-225}{2n}$.

$U(f,Q_n)$ = $\sum \limits_{i-1}^{n}({-10} + \frac{15i}{n})(\frac{15}{n})$ = $\frac{225-75n}{2n}$.

Hence, $U(f,Q_n)$ - $L(f,Q_n)$ = $\frac{225}{n}$. We want $\frac{225}{n} < 0.001$, meaning $n>225000$. Hence, a partition Q satisfying this property splits the interval $[-10,5]$ into $2250000$ equal intervals. How bad is this - have I made any errors or missed out on something obvious for solving ?

**I think my mistake is finding $m_i$ and $M_i$ because I did this assuming $f(x)$ = $x$ rather than piecewise.**

**Can someone please show me how to correctly calculate $m_i$ and then I can complete the rest ??!!**

Comment: What is $P$?  Using the given $f$ rather than $f(x)=x$ will change what you get for $M_i$ and $m_i$.  The piecewise part only affects the partition that contains 0.  But if you know what your mistake is, why can't you go back and correct it?

Comment: $P$ is a partition of $[-10,5]$. I'm going to go back and recalculate $M_i$ and $m_i$ and reupdate my post. the reason why I am confused is because when calculating $m_i$ and $M_i$, wouldn't the values be different approaching $x=0$? Basically, is there an alternative way to solve this or am I on the right lines ?

Comment: @Teepeemm Is my general partition correct $Q_n$?

Comment: $Q_n$ is a partition of the interval, but you don't find $M_i$ and $m_i$ correctly.  $P$ is a partition of $[-10,5]$, but you never use it in your problem, so it's confusing to have.  Have you sketched $f$?  You can do find a good $Q$ with only three intervals.

Comment: @Teepeemm Yes I sketched it. For $x<0$ it is equal to $1$, for $x=0$ it is equal to $4$ , and for $x>0$ it is equal to $3$. I don't need $P$ for this question except to note that for $Q_n$ the endpoints are $-10$ and $5$. I don't know how to find $m_i$ and $M_i$ correctly from here and to end up answering the question. This is what I require help on please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume that $M_i=\sup\{f(x):x_{i-1}\le x\le x_i\}$ and $m_i=\inf\{f(x):x_{i-1}\le x\le x_i\}$ (you should double check your notes on how you've defined $M_i$ and $m_i$, as this may be slightly different).  Let's apply that to your example $P=\{-10,-2,0,1,5\}$:

- On $[-10,-2]$, $f$ is constantly 1, so $M_1=m_1=1$.
- On $[-2,0]$, $f$ is constantly 1 except at $x=0$, where $f(0)=4$.  This means that $M_2=4$ and $m_2=1$.
- On $[0,1]$, $f(0)=4$, otherwise $f$ is constantly 3.  This means that $M_3=4$ and $m_3=3$.
- On $[1,5]$, $f$ is constantly 3, so $M_4=m_4=3$.

This means that
\begin{align*}
L(f,P)&=(1)(8)+(1)(2)+(3)(1)+(3)(4)=25,\qquad\text{while}\\
U(f,P)&=(1)(8)+(4)(2)+(4)(1)+(3)(4)=32,\qquad\text{with a difference}\\
U(f,P)-L(f,P)&=(0)(8)+(3)(2)+(1)(1)+(0)(4)=7.
\end{align*}
The interesting thing to notice is that when $f$ is constant, then $M=m$, and they subtract to give zero when you find $U-L$.  This means that any partition can use large intervals over the regions where $f$ is constant, and only needs small intervals when $f$ is changing.  And in this case, $f$ is changing only around $0$, which allows you to use relatively few intervals overall.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking today and I realised that away from $0$ regardless of the intervals the values are the same, so I need to “zoom” in on $x$ values close to $0$. I think this way I will be able to solve it. I was thinking of using $\delta$, so like I could introduce the terms $0-\delta,0,0+\delta$. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Exactly.  And you can probably even skip $0$, and just use $\pm\delta$.

Comment: Thanks for your help and sorry for bothering you. I think I’m getting better at these things when taking time to do them. Thanks again